# How can I adapt an existing Google Apps Script to import CSV of same name?

Tags: google-sheets

I found this code for importing csv files from drive. I do this hourly, and always import the updated (only) copy in drive called  "inv.csv", so I'm trying to adapt the code to not require this to be typed in every time

the exiting code is this:

```
function onOpen() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Search in all files", functionName: "search"}];

  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Load from CSV file", functionName: "importFromCSV"}];

  ss.addMenu("Search Google Drive", searchMenuEntries);

  ss.addMenu("CSV", csvMenuEntries);

}


function importFromCSV() {

  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the file in your Google Drive to import (e.g. myFile.csv):");
   
  var searchTerm = "title = '"+fileName+"'";
   
  // search for our file

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchTerm)

  var csvFile = "";
   
  // Loop through the results

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();

    // assuming the first file we find is the one we want

    if (file.getName() == fileName) {

      // get file as a string

      csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();

      break;
    }
  }

  // parseCsv will return a [][] array we can write to a sheet

  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // boom data to a sheet

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); 

}
```

---

What I've tried:
I thought to remove the variable fileName completely, and define searchTerm as a static string, making the first bit

function importFromCSV() {

<strike>var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the file in your Google Drive to import (e.g. myFile.csv):");</strike>

var searchTerm = "title = 'inv.csv'";

---

but I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I should have defined fileName, not searchTerm, as the former appeared later in the code.

```
var fileName = "inv.csv";
```